# Open External url using DataNavigateUrlFields in GridView

Tags: datagridview

I am trying to open External URLs using DataNavigateUrlFields in datagrid. The source for the datagrid is an XML file. when I trying to open the link, I am getting like this -
**`http://localhost:4153/MyProject/www.google.com`**
But I want to open www.google.com

Please help....

Thanks,
Vikas

Comment: Thanks a ton Saar, I tried that also...But no luck...It would be great if you could provide the exact syntax...

-Vikas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set Target to self and Page opens in a new window as a popup instead of just redirecting to Contain Page.

```
    <asp:DataGrid ID="DataGrid1" runat="server">
        <Columns>
            <asp:HyperLinkColumn HeaderText="id" DataTextField="id" Target="_self" 
                                 DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/contain.aspx?id={0}"
                                 DataNavigateUrlField="id">
            </asp:HyperLinkColumn>
            </Columns>
   </asp:DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1):

To open the External URLs it must start with the "HTTP". So here in your case if you want to open [www.google.com](http://www.google.com),

please make sure the URL is in the following format:
http://www.google.com  or http://google.com

This will make the google site open.

If we don't use the "HTTP", the string "`http://localhost:4153/MyProject/`" will be added to the url and we will not be able to open the external url. Please try the above option and you will have it working.

Answer (score 0):

use parameter "DataNavigateUrlFormatString".

Answer (score 0):

use parameter "`DataNavigateUrlFormatString`" and web address must begin with http or ~